# AsyncSocket Delay Sending Data

Tags: java, iphone, networking, delay, asyncsocket

So I'm writing an application for my iphone that networks to my computer running a java application using AsyncSocket. But when I try sending data from my iPhone to the java application, the data only prints out when I exit the iPhone application. Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but it sounds like you are not flushing the output to a socket (it probably gets flushed by force when it closes, when the application closes).